# Html/php file of custom options in magento

Tags: magento

I have added a separate product with custom options for that product from admin. But the view which i am getting on front-end has to be edited because i want to give my own styling for that product only. So which are the files from where the custom option html is coming.

Comment: enable file path hint from admin, so you can look from where custom option html is coming

Answer (score 1):

1. [Turn on template path hints](http://www.redlightblinking.com/blog/magento-tutorials/magento-debugging-how-to-debug-template-paths-logging-and-display-errors)
2. In the "Design" tab for that product in the Admin, specify a different template/templates for the blocks which you want to change.